# Drawing subset of a bitmap to a canvas?

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm writing my first app of any consequence, so I may be going about this the entire wrong way, but...

I have a resource image that is 1600x880.  I'd like to fill the entire screen with a subset of that image to my canvas, such that an arbitrary x,y coordinate marks the top-left corner drawn at the top-left corner of the screen.  For instance, if I was viewing this image on an N1 and I entered x=100 and y=50, I'd expect to see from 100,50 to 580,850 since it's display area is 480x800.

I think I need to use `Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)`.  But, no matter what I plug in to either Rect (even if it's a perfectly sane set of values that shouldn't butt up against any edges of the image), I end up with an unexpected area or a grossly stretched/smooshed output.

I've tried using various combinations of calculations involving `display.getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, `canvas.getWidth() and getHeight()`, and `bitmap.getWidth() and getHeight()` but nothing seems to be working.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: No error.  Area.  As in an unwanted region of the image gets drawn.

Comment: is your resource in `res/drawable-nodpi`? if not, is it possibly getting scaled?

Comment: Nevermind. The problem is solved for now, or has morphed into a different problem completely.  The emulator, for some reason, was rendering the image different than the actual phone was.  On the phone, it was displaying as expected.

Comment: be careful that the emulator isn't running a different form of Android than the phone. If that's the case, your app may not work properly on other phones besides the one you are testing on.